# NServiceBus - Messages are going to Error queue directly without processing

Tags: nservicebus

We have an issue with a windows service which uses nServiceBus. At some random moment, the nServiceBus stops processing messages and direct them directly to Error queue, and I have to restart the service. After the restart, the messages arrived in the input message queue are handled, and everything gets back to normal. If we re-drop the messages which were went to error queue, it is processing it successfully without any issue.

We are using log4net logs to audit the message flow and storing in DB. The NServiceBus Handler stops to log in log4net. After we restart the windows service (NServiceBus) then it start to log again. We are NOT able to redproduce this issue in development environment. We are suspecting this could be a NService Bus Memory Leak issue. But we don't know how to confirm this issue and resolve the same.

We are planning to move this Windows Service (NServiceBus) to different server as a trial and error basis. Did anyone face this issue ever and resolved it? Please help us to resolve this issue as it is causing more troubles in Production environment.

NServiceBus Version that we are using : 2.0.0.1329

Message queue and windows service are in the same machine.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you're running on a version of NServiceBus that is about 5 years old and is no longer supported. While I could give you the standard recommendation of upgrading to a more current release, it could very well be that some of the configuration APIs that you're using have been made obsolete so you may need to make some modifications there and/or in the app.configs.

I'm sorry to say that there probably isn't a better solution for you at this time.

In general, I'd suggest trying to track the NServiceBus releases somewhat more closely. If you're within 6-12 months of the current release, you should generally be in good shape.